# Como capturar somente último registro de uma tabela?

Tags: codeigniter-3

A query pura (sql) abaixo, só me retorna uma linha da tabela, ocorre que estou trabalhando com duas tabelas (Processo e Andamento) sendo que andamento possui como chave estrangeira a chave primária de Processo.

```
select fkcodprocesso, dtandamento, descricao from andamento 
order by str_to_date(dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y') desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de setar a tabela processo depois do "from", já que você esta usando as duas tabela (Processo e andamento) você tem que referenciar as duas, sera bom voce nomia as tabelas para ficar mais fácil ex:

select pc.fkcodprocesso, at.dtandamento, at.descricao FROM processo pc, andamento at order by str_to_date(at.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y') desc limit 1;

Comment: na verdade trata-se de um relatório do meu sistema, onde eu preciso listar todos o processos exibindo o último andamento dos mesmos, da tabela andamento. Tem ideia de como fazer isso no Codeigniter @Marco Sales?